# Join an array with a single element in terraform or jq

Tags: terraform, jq

I have the following json data which I get from `data "external"` in terraform

```
{
  "ips": ["192.168.0.1",
          "192.168.0.2",
          "192.168.0.3"],

  "port": "8080"
}
```

I want to construct the target address in the format `ip:port`

The desired output as follows:

```
["192.168.0.1:8080",
"192.168.0.2:8080",
"192.168.0.3:8080"]
```

I am trying to do this in `terraform` but I am fine with a solution that uses `jq`

The closest thing I could find is the string `join` function that takes a separator but it won't add the port to the last element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the output format of jq is ok for you as well, then you can use this :

```
jq '[ .ips[] + ":" + .port ]' input
```

---

```
[
  "192.168.0.1:8080",
  "192.168.0.2:8080",
  "192.168.0.3:8080"
]
```

`.ips[]` iterates over the ip array while keeping the root object as input, so that `.port` is available. Then the `... + ":" + .port` expression is applied to each element, producing a stream of transformed values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a working solution with terraform's `join` then manually append the port to the last IP, but will be happy to find a cleaner solution

terraform snippet

```
format("%s:%s", 
      join(
         format(":%s,", port),
         ips
       ),
      port)
```

Comment: This was a terraform snippet, I think the same approach can be achieved in `jq`